# Slim Framework and Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, composer-php, slim

I'm using `Slim Framework` together with `Laravel's Eloquent ORM` and this is my code:

**User.php**

```
class User extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    protected $table = 'accounts';
}
```

**index.php**

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Models
include 'app/models/User.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

// Database information
$settings = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'database' => 'photo_mgmt',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
);

$container = new Illuminate\Container\Container;
$connFactory = new \Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory($container);
$conn = $connFactory->make($settings);
$resolver = new \Illuminate\Database\ConnectionResolver();
$resolver->addConnection('default', $conn);
$resolver->setDefaultConnection('default');
\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setConnectionResolver($resolver);

$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    $users = \User::all();
    echo $users->toJson();
});

$app->run();
```

As you can see in my code, I have to include the `User.php` file in my `index.php`. But what if I have multiple models? Can I just include a folder and all models will also be included so that it won't look messy including every model file in my index.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I'm using this piece of code I saw

```
foreach (glob("app/models/*.php") as $filename)
{
    include $filename;
}
```

Is there a cleaner looking way?

Comment: Add your model folder to the autoloader (composer) and put them all in a namespace for clean code :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Composer to automatically include classes from your project.  Let's say your `composer.json` file lives in `app`.  Then you can use the `classmap` attribute in your `composer.json` to automatically include all classes in `models`:

```
...
"require": {
    "php" : ">=5.4.0",
    "slim/slim" : "2.*",
    "illuminate/database" : "5.0.33",
    ...
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap" : [
        "models"
    ]
}
```

The `classmap` tells Composer to map all classes in the specified directory(ies).  Then, all you need to do is run `composer update` to update Composer's list of includes whenever you add a new file to this directory.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, there is a much cleaner way to do this, namely autoloading.

It boils down to the use of [spl_autoload_register()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) and of a custom class loader.

The principle is to mimic the namespace with the file hierarchy and load these accordingly to the namespace:

```
$loader = function load($class)
{
    include __DIR__."/app/$class.php";
}
spl_autoload_register($loader);
$user = new models\User();
```

This will automatically include the file located at app/models/User.php. It is a good practice to respect uppercases in your namespace; if you namespace is Model\User, the directory should respect the casing (app/Model/User.php)

---

The problem with your current solution:

```
foreach (glob("app/models/*.php") as $filename)
{
    include $filename;
}
```

is that it will load all classes, even if the script will not use them. Registering an autoloader will prevent that, only loading the necessary code.